Find a function $f$ which is discontinuous at $1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},...$ but continuous at all other points
When solving this problem my first instinct was to simply make $1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},...$ not in the domain of a function $f$,but $f$ is continuous for all other $a$ . So I arrived at
$$f(x)=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x-\frac{1}{k}}$$
The second part of the question is the same as  the first, except we must make $f$ discontinuous at $0$. So by the same logic as before.
$$f(x)=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x(x-\frac{1}{k})}$$
Intuitively I believe that these two functions are continuous at all points except the explicit, intentional, discontinuities.
If anyone could tell me that these solution are valid , or point me in the right direction that'd be great thanks!

You do have to make it defined at those points, however.

What is, say, $f(3)$? What about $f(2/5)$?

This approach can work, but you'll need to fiddle with it a bit to make sure your sum converges. You also still need to specify the value the function takes at $1,\frac12,\frac13$, etc.

It is probably a bad idea to write this as an infinite product.  But if you do, you have to check convergence.

A simple function is $f(x)=\frac{1}{\lfloor 1/x\rfloor}$ on $(0,1]$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq0$ and $f(x)=2$ for $x>1.$

BTW, my  $f(3)$  and $f(2/5)$ questions were really whether the infinite products converge or not.  You might like to take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product

@Malady Why do I have to make them defined at those points?

@EdwardFalls because discontinuity is a property of points in the domain.

Consider the function
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x,x\notin\{1,1/2,1/3,\dots\}\\0,x\in\{1,1/2,1/3,\dots\}\end{cases}$$
$f$ is continuous everywhere apart from $\{1,1/2,1/3,\dots\}$.
Consider the function
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}f(x),x\ne0\\1,x=0\end{cases}$$
$g$ is continuous everywhere apart from $\{0,1,1/2,1/3,\dots\}$.
